# What word describes answering an unspoken question?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an English word that describes the action of understanding a question that is about to be asked, and answering it before it is verbalized.

For example: this would be *without* 'it':

> Person 1: I love dogs.
>
> Person 2: Which breed of dogs are your favorite?
>
> Person 1: Golden retrievers.

And this would be with 'it':

> Person 1: I love golden retriever dogs.

Answer (score 4):

Person 1 is giving a [pre-emptive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/preemptive) answer:

> taken as a measure against something possible, anticipated, or feared; preventive; deterrent:

*a preemptive tactic against a ruthless business rival.*

The question is *anticipated* by person 1 and so they give a pre-emptive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I would think you could use [presumptive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/presumptive) to describe this sort of response.

```
Person 1: I love dogs.


Person 2(presumptively):I like Golden retrievers.
```

Certainly, other situations might suggest other terms. But the question here, I think, leads to *presumption*